# How to swap the value of the field on one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database in Access 2010 for all the keys that we have in our school campus. The table is CampusBuilding and it has the field named: KeyNumber. So, on this field we have about 600 keys listed, and each one has a different number (no keys with the same number). Sometimes I need to change the number of the key to another number. So here is one example:
List of number from 1 to 8 in on field named: KeyNumber:

8

6

7

3

2

1

5

4

Here is what I would like to do.
In a form named: CampusBuildingKeys, I go to the record that has the field with the number 8, and I want to replace number 8 for 7. When I type 7 for this field, the number 8 goes to the field where number 7 is. That means that the record that had number 7, now is number 8.
I hope you can understand what I want to say.
I'm not very experienced with Access yet, so I appreciate any suggestions!
Thank you

Comment: no - not clear.  you just want to change the 8 to a 7 - but then what happens to the old number 7 row?

Comment: Sorry Randy, I was away and just now I was able to conect. Just answering your question, "but then what happens to the old number 7 row", the old number 7 turns number 8. I hope it is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this *might* work...

```
UPDATE CampusBuildingKeys
SET    KeyNumber = Iif(KeyNumber = 7, 8, 7)
WHERE  KeyNumber IN (7, 8)
```

Comment: I did not the ternary operator was an option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest wrapping the operation in a stored procedure. I am not familiar with the exact Access syntax, but this thread (http://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/07/29/sql-server-stored-procedure-guide-for-microsoft-access-part-1/) should be a good starting point.

Create a stored procedure that taken in 2 parameters (key1, key2) and performs the equivalent of the (kinda-hack) statements below:

```
UPDATE table SET key=-100 WHERE key=key2
UPDATE table SET key=key2 WHERE key=key1
UPDATE table SET key=key1 WHERE key=-100
```

I use the `-100` value to temporarily point to rows that had key-2.